# Erlang List filter question

Tags: list, filter, erlang

I have record in which one field is list:

```
-record(state, {
        rcpt :: list()
            }).
```

Rcpt field has some values =

> ["localhost", "admin"]

I need filter this list. For example i need field localhost.

I try:

```
List = lists:filter(fun(X) -> LocalHost =:= X end, State#state.rcpt),
```

but List is empty.

What's wrong i do?

I don't understand it. Look:

```
io:format(State#state.rcpt),
    %% output: localhost
HaveRcpt = lists:member("localhost", State#state.rcpt ),
io:format(HaveRcpt);
    %% output false
```

But if i use:

```
io:format(State#state.rcpt),
HaveRcpt = lists:member("localhost", lists:nth(1,State#state.rcpt) ),
io:format(HaveRcpt);
%% true
```

Thank you.

Comment: Comment on your edit and the two statements you make: `1. State=#state{rcpt=["localhost","admin"]}` and `2. false=lists:member("localhost",State#state.rcpt)` are contradictions. Please print your exact format on State and its field rcpt.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the full value isn't your real objective to see if that value is just a member of the list or not?

```
HaveRcpt = lists:member( "localhost", State#state.rcpt ) 
% HaveRcpt will have value true of false
```

That may be used like

```
case lists:member( "admin", State#state.rcpt ) of 
 true -> is_admin;
 false -> is_no_admin
end
```

If the value may be repeated several times for any reasons and you want all of those fields, you may use the lists:filter/2 like this.

```
lists:filter(fun(X) -> "localhost"==X end, State#state.rcpt)
or
[ X || X <- State#state.rcpt, X=="localhost" ]
```

You introduced a variable LocalHost in your example. This must be the exact value as your element ("localhost","admin") to ever return anything else then a empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's better to set default value for *rcpt* field:

```
-record(state, {
    rcpt = [] :: [string()]
    }).
```

Then you need to set *rcpt* field value correctly (it's better to encapsulate this operation in a setup function):

```
 S = #state{rcpt=["localhost", "admin"]}
```

And after all that you can use [lists:member](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#member-2) as expected:

```
true = lists:member("localhost", S#state.rcpt),
true = lists:member("admin", S#state.rcpt),
false = lists:member("other", S#state.rcpt)
```

Answer (score 0):

If

```
HaveRcpt = lists:member("localhost", lists:nth(1,State#state.rcpt) ),
io:format(HaveRcpt).
%% true
```

then your State#state.rcpt have to contain [["localhost"]|_]

```
1> lists:member("localhost", lists:nth(1,["localhost","admin"]) ).
false
2> lists:member("localhost", lists:nth(1,[["localhost"],"admin"]) ).
true
```

If you would have correct content it would work as expected

```
3> L = ["localhost","admin"].                                                                                                                                                                        
["localhost","admin"]
4> lists:filter(fun(X) -> "localhost" =:= X end, L).
["localhost"]
5> [X || X<-L, "localhost" =:= X].                                                                                                                                                                   
["localhost"]
```